# default selected from hidden value dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanna set a default value for dropdown select.

For example `krik` value is `('pt123', 'washington', 'rob  case', 'rob', 'rob')`. I wanna set selection based on val4 which is call card id.

**Problem** : value from `krik` to `input hidden` is functioning.. but to set selected is fail.. When I set alert it is show that the value is undefined..

How can I get the value from hidden field to compare that `$sel` condition..

Pls help.. I have already try for days.. It make me over thinking for days.

```js
function krik(val1, val2,val3,val4,val5) {
    var calID = val1;
    var calLoc = val2;
    var calCase = val3;
    var calCar = val4;
    var casecod = val5;
    $("#formkes-dialog").dialog("open");
    $('#formkes-dialog').dialog({
         title: $('#formkes-dialog').prop('title') + calCar
    });
    $("#CallerId").val(calID);
    $("#CrimeLocation").val(calLoc);
    $("#CaseDesc").val(calCase);
    $("#casecod").val(casecod);
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden"  name="casecod" id="casecod" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- var mytextvalue = document.getElementById("casecod").value; -->
    alert(document.getElementById('casecod').val); 
</script>
          
 <?php 
     $sel = $_GET['casecod'];
 ?>

 <select name="CaseCode" id="CaseCode" >

     <option >Pilih</option>

     <option selected='<?php (($sel == "case1")?"selected":"") ?>' value="case1">Gaduh</option>

     <option selected='<?php (($sel == "case2")?"selected":"") ?>' value="case2">Rompak</option>

     <option selected='<?php (($sel == "case3)?"selected":"") ?>' value="case3">Kemalangan</option>

 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

First specify value in hidden field.

```
Eg:

<input type="hidden"  name="casecod" id="casecod" value="demo_value" />
```

Replace js with following:-

```
Use '.value' instead of '.val'.
<script type="text/javascript">
            <!-- var mytextvalue = document.getElementById("casecod").value; -->
            alert(document.getElementById('casecod').value); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**check it**

```js
function krik(val1, val2,val3,val4,val5) {
    var calID = val1;
    var calLoc = val2;
    var calCase = val3;
    var calCar = val4;
    var casecod = val5;
    $("#formkes-dialog").dialog("open");
    $('#formkes-dialog').dialog({
         title: $('#formkes-dialog').prop('title') + calCar
    });
    $("#CallerId").val(calID);
    $("#CrimeLocation").val(calLoc);
    $("#CaseDesc").val(calCase);
    $("#casecod").val(casecod);
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden"  name="casecod" id="casecod" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- var mytextvalue = document.getElementById("casecod").value; -->
    alert(document.getElementById('casecod').value); 
</script>
          
 <?php 
     $sel = $_GET['casecod'];
 ?>

 <select name="CaseCode" id="CaseCode" >

     <option value="pilih" >Pilih</option>

     <option selected='<?php (($sel == "case1")?"selected":"") ?>' value="case1">Gaduh</option>

     <option selected='<?php (($sel == "case2")?"selected":"") ?>' value="case2">Rompak</option>

     <option selected='<?php (($sel == "case3")?"selected":"") ?>' value="case3">Kemalangan</option>

 </select>
```

Comment: tq all.. i got the answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

Also correct the option From

```
<option selected='<?php (($sel == "case3)?"selected":"") ?>' value="case3">Kemalangan</option>
```

To

```
  <option selected='<?php (($sel == "case3")?"selected":"") ?>' value="case3">Kemalangan</option>
```

Then check.

Answer (score 0):

i juz got the answer.. it is juz becoz i dun declare on top of page for query to get the casecod data.. :).... thank all.. juz a simple thing but use to be hard..

```html
<?php

session_start();


require_once("includes/conn.php");

$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM report WHERE Status = '1'";
$result = mysql_query($sql_select);
$test = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$CaseCode =$test['CaseCode'];

?>

 <select name="CaseCode" id="CaseCode">

            <option>--choose one--</option>

            <option selected="<?php (($CaseCode == "Kidnap" || $CaseCode == "kidnap")?'selected':'') ?>"          value="Kidnap">Kidnapped</option>

            <option selected="<?php (($CaseCode == "Robbery" || $CaseCode == "robbery")?'selected':'') ?>" value="Robbery">Robbery</option>

            <option selected="<?php (($CaseCode == "Wilderness" || $CaseCode == "wilderness")?'selected':'') ?>" value="Wilderness">Wilderness</option>

          </select>
```